# Consultation regarding the method of querying currently executing SQL statements in CnosDB

Tags: cnosdb

1、show queries;

[image]

2、SELECT * FROM information_schema.QUERIES;
[image]

While checking for slow-performing SQL queries today, I came across these two query methods in the documentation and found them quite interesting.
What is the difference between these two SQL statements in the document besides the difference in displayed fields?